# Why URDF is not deprecated?

Tags: ros, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am following the tutorials on ROS and gazebo and I am really getting confused as to the current state of URDF and SDF.

The overall question is: if SDF supersedes URDF, why is URDF kept?

Now getting into details:

- You now need 2 descriptions of your scene (URDF and SDF)... Which is weird. Of course you can use *gzsdf* to do the conversion but

1. It read the tool does not handle complex scenes,
2. And you end up having to write a URDF with the hacky *gazebo* tags for simulation parameters rather than using the native SDF simulation parameters

- URDF is sometimes marked deprecated, sometimes you read there is no plan to get rid of it ([here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/62/sdf-vs-urdf-what-should-one-use/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/147836/is-urdf-depricated-are-there-replacement-sdf-tools/))
- SDF seems to only be supported in gazebo, what is the support state for SDF in MoveIt, RViz...and the other tools?
- When following the initial Gazebo tutorials, you are pushed to use SDF. Now when reaching the tutorials on the connection between ROS and gazebo they only talk about URDF, this is very misleading

Is this confusion due to a transitional state from URDF to SDF which last longer than expected, or is it supposed to last forever?

So **what is the best practise today to use URDF and SDF on a large project**? Should we specify things in URDF (including gazebo tags for links, joints and robots), convert to SDF using *gzsdf* and cross fingers that the *gzsdf* conversion works?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186793/why-urdf-is-not-deprecated?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Hsu answered this really well. http://answers.ros.org/question/41294/gazebo-with-controller/?answer=41770#post-id-41770

-Dash

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-16**:
Thanks! Hence what is the best practise today to use URDF and SDF on a large project? You write URDF by hand and convert to SDF using gzsdf?

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-17**:
@DEvnoW, I beg to disagree. @hsu explained a situation that was temporary two years ago. It is not your fault nor it is hsu's but two years w/o any changes on a situation like this, can hardly be considered an "answer". It was a reply, yes, but neither answer, nor solution.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-18**:
@ccapriotti, I agree with you that the situation is clunky and not optimal. As this is a rather fundamental problem that everybody has to cope with I guess there is an obvious answer to the problem on a day to day basis. Any idea of the workaround to the problem on large projects?